# How to do the spacing?

Tags: spacing

[image]

Could somebody please help me out with this.
I want the three functions to start at the same place after the names as in the picture.

I'm not sure in which environment I should do it.

This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

  \item
  Fr\'{e}chet:
  $\Phi_{\alpha}(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    0 \quad \quad & x \leq 0 \\
    e^{-x^{-\alpha}} & x>0
  \end{cases}
  \quad \quad \alpha >0$

  \item
  Weibull:
  $\Psi_{\alpha}(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    e^{-(-x)^\alpha} \quad \quad & x \leq 0 \\
    1 & x>0
  \end{cases}
  \quad \quad \alpha >0$

  \item
  Gumbel: $\Lambda (x) = e^{e^{-x}} \quad \quad x \in \R$

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a small. complete document setting up the problem so we don't have to start from scratch and guess what you have so far.

Comment: \begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Fr\'{e}chet: $\Phi_{\alpha}(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \quad \quad & x \leq 0  \\ e^{-x^{-\alpha}} & x>0\end{cases} \quad \quad \alpha >0$

\item Weibull: $\Psi_{\alpha}(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-(-x)^\alpha} \quad \quad & x \leq 0  \\ 1 & x>0\end{cases} \quad \quad \alpha >0$

\item Gumbel: $\Lambda (x) = e^{e^{-x}} \quad \quad x \in \R$

\end{itemize}
\end{document}

This is what I have so far..

Comment: @Paul Welcome to the site! You should have edited your question to include this information. You can also apply code sample markdown, as I have done, by highlighting the code and pressing the button (which looks like { }) or by hitting Ctrl - k

Answer (score 3):

I found the `alignat` environment to be most useful: it allows you to specify alignment at multiple places in a list of equations. Here, I aligned at the start of each function and the start of `\alpha > 0`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\text{Fr\'echet:}\quad\qquad &\Phi_\alpha(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    0, & x \le 0\\
    e^{-x^{-\alpha}}, & x > 0
  \end{cases}
  &\alpha > 0,\\
\text{Weibull:}\quad\qquad&\Psi_\alpha(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    e^{-(-x)^\alpha}, & x \le 0\\
    1, & x > 0
  \end{cases}
  \quad
  &\alpha > 0,\\
\text{Gumbel:}\quad\qquad&\Lambda(x) = e^{-e^{-x}},\ x\in\mathbb R.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the three names don't start at the same position.  Rather, the colons `:` are aligned.

Comment: I thought mine were aligned at the colons (since there's a `\quad\qquad` space between each colon and the alignment specifier); are they not vertically aligned? (I would've put a separator at the colons directly, but something strange happens with alignment and the `cases` environment if I do so.)

Comment: That's what I wrote: The colons are aligned, but not the first letters of the words.  I would prefer that the words themselves are aligned, but I don't know what the OP would prefer.

Comment: @jarauh: I see; my mistake. I thought OP aligned at the colons, and I'm not sure my strategy would work for aligning the beginnings of the words (maybe everything should be put into an `array` for that case). Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to suggest another solution using `alignat`.  How does my solution differ from the other `alignat` solutions?

1. I am using the colon of the text, the equals sign, and the `\alpha` as alignment points.
2. I kept your `\R` macro and added the additional `\ee` macro which typesets Euler's number upright.
3. Instead of `\quad\quad` you can use `\qquad`.

In the future please also provide the `\documentclass` and `\usepackage` section required to typeset the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand*\R{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand*\ee{\mathrm{e}}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
  \text{Fr\'{e}chet:}&\qquad&
  \Phi_{\alpha}(x) &=
  \begin{cases}
    0, & x \leq 0 \\
    \ee^{-x^{-\alpha}}, & x>0
  \end{cases}
  &\quad \alpha > 0 \;, \\
  \text{Weibull:}&\qquad&
  \Psi_{\alpha}(x) &=
  \begin{cases}
    \ee^{-(-x)^\alpha}, & x \leq 0 \\
    1, & x>0
  \end{cases}
  &\quad \alpha > 0 \;, \\
  \text{Gumbel:}&\qquad&
  \Lambda (x) &= \ee^{\ee^{-x}},\quad x \in \R \;.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Your answer seems to imply that “e” should be upright, which I can't agree with. However, it can be a good idea to have a command for it, so the formatting of the letter in the context of exponentials can be changed in a single place.

Comment: @egreg I followed the advice from [this TUGboat](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf): “Numerical constants must be set in roman type; this is perhaps the most neglected rule, but it applies to e = 2.718 281 8…, the base of natural logarithms […] The reason behind this is to avoid confusion between the base of natural logarithms and the elementary electric charge.”

Comment: That's for engineering and physics. My experience is that most mathematicians aren't afraid of confusing between the number and the elementary electric charge and so use an italic “e” instead of the horrible upright one.

Comment: @egreg: though I agree that _e_ should be italicized, the [Wikipedia page on American mathematical typography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_conventions_in_mathematical_formulae) mentions that upright constants is the ISO standard; I don't know what the standard is in Europe, though.

Comment: @ArunDebray The ISO standard is, as I said, for engineering and physics. It doesn't concern pure mathematics.

Comment: in addition to @egreg's quibble, the names are aligned on the colon, which isn't what the op has.  easily fixed with a couple more `&`s and adjustment to numeric argument for `alignat*`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `array` environments to align items vertically in four places.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mleftright}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{l@{\qquad}l@{{}={}}l l}
\text{Fr\'{e}chet:} &
\Phi_{\alpha}(x) &
\mleft\{ \begin{array}{@{}ll}
    0,                & x \leq 0 \\
    e^{-x^{-\alpha}}, & x>0
\end{array}\mright. & 
\alpha >0\\[4ex]
\text{Weibull:} &
\Psi_{\alpha}(x) &
\mleft\{ \begin{array}{@{}ll}
    e^{-(-x)^\alpha},  & x \leq 0 \\
    1,                 & x>0
\end{array}\mright. & 
\alpha >0\\[3ex]
\text{Gumbel:} & 
\Lambda (x)  & 
e^{e^{-x}}, x \in \R
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{Fr\'{e}chet:} \hspace{4mm} \Phi_{\alpha}(x) &=
\begin{cases}
0 & x \leq 0 \\
e^{-x^{-\alpha}} & x>0
\end{cases}
\hspace{5mm} \alpha >0 \\
\text{Weibull:} \hspace{4mm} \Psi_{\alpha}(x) &=
\begin{cases}
e^{-(-x)^\alpha} & x \leq 0 \\
1 & x>0
\end{cases} 
\hspace{5mm} \alpha >0 \\
\text{Gumbel:} \hspace{4mm}  \Lambda (x) &= e^{e^{-x}} \hspace{5mm} 
x \in \mathcal{R}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: code 1]

Comment: The names are not aligned at all, neither at their first letters, nor at the colons.